# Review response to quite positive review comments - first grant

Tags: funding

I recently received the review reports for my first grant. All four scores were 5 out of 6. The comments are also mostly positive. Two criticised a bit about the pathways to impact and the support from the department, but nothing major.

What do you think I should write in my response? I've drafted a version and made a response to each point raised by the reviewers. However, my mentor thinks that probably the reviewers were not enthusiastic enough or something like that - and that’s the really serious thing, and that I need to emphasise my proposal is great, not to answer the "lazy" questions from reviewers.

I am a bit confused. What shall I write then?

Comment: Did your mentor say what makes them think that the reviewers weren't enthusiastic? You may also want to say a little about what the scores represent.

Answer (score 4):

I assume your question is about one of the UK Research Councils, probably EPSRC. If that's true, then 5555 is currently considered quite a *low* score, and such a proposal is not likely to be put forward for funding during the Panel meeting (unless you have a year with unusually low competition level, or someone in Panel is really keen to fund your research). In fact, the competition levels in EPSRC right now are so insane, that even proposals scored 6666 are not always supported.

The fact that you have "lazy" comments from Reviewers makes your situation even more difficult, as you are not given a good chance to stand for yourself by answering the questions. Your mentor is right that at this stage you have to write a really brilliant Response to Reviewers to make your proposal fundable. 
Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with panels and proposal review is that it's impossible to read from reviews what reviewers or the panel really thought unless you've been on panels many times and have experienced the dynamics of discussions there. As such, I read your question that you are interpreting the reviews you have in a more literal way, whereas your adviser (who may have been on panels before) reads them through the lens of what the reviewers were probably thinking when they wrote them. She is probably right, and you'd do well following her advice.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, for many scientific review panels, the person to talk to at this stage is the Program Officer or somebody in a similar role, who works within the organizational structure of the funding agency and who was in the room while the proposal was discussed.  Such a person is often very skilled at helping the investigator determine what the mood was in the room (or on the phone) while the grant was being discussed, and can help you frame your response.

I don't know the mechanisms where you are, but you should see if there is such person in your local infrastructure, but I'm sure your mentors will.

I wouldn't agree with Dmitry's assessment that across the board 5's are a *low* score.  Fact is, there are so many proposals compared to awards granted in many fields, that many fine grants that deserve funding just don't make the cut.  Reviewers feel bad about it, funding institutes feel bad about it, and obviously investigators feel bad about it, but that's the life we lead.

My recommendation for how to come out the other side of this, and work your way into the "funded" column, is to partake in, or start up, a formal mentorship program where the experienced help new investigators.  Get some people with established grant records to preview grants before they go in, even starting discussion as the proposal is in its formative stages, and help newbies tone them up before submission.  At this point, you have what we in the US call "pink sheets" with the reviews.  Get three or four funded investigators to read your grant and your pink sheets, and help you plan a response.